# How does this deviation come out after I use Evaluate and Plot in Mathematica？

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, precision, evaluation, pde, deviation

I ran into this problem when I try to solve a partial differential equation. Here is my code:

```
dd = NDSolve[{D[tes[t, x], t] ==D[tes[t, x], x, x] + Exp[-1/(tes[t, x])],
   tes[t, 0] == 1, tes[t, -1] == 1, tes[0, x] == 1}, {tes[t, x]}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -1, 0}]

f[t_, x_] = tes[t, x] /. dd
kkk = FunctionInterpolation[Integrate[Exp[-1.1/( Evaluate[f[t, x]])], {x, -1, 0}], {t, 0, 0.05}]
kkg[t_] = Integrate[Exp[-1.1/( Evaluate[f[t, x]])], {x, -1, 0}]
Plot[Evaluate[kkk[t]] - Evaluate[kkg[t]], {t, 0, 0.05}]
N[kkg[0.01] - kkk[0.01], 1]
```

It's strange that the deviation showed in the graph reaches up to more than `5*10^-7` around `t=0.01`, while it's only `-3.88578*10^-16` when calculated by `N[kkg[0.01] - kkk[0.01], 1]`, I wonder how this error comes out.

By the way, I feel it strange that the output of `N[kkg[0.01] - kkk[0.01], 1]` has so many decimal places, I've set the precision as 1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Mathematica* 7 the plot I get does not show a peak at 0.01:

```
Plot[kkk[t] - kkg[t], {t, 0, 0.05}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There *is* a peak at about `0.00754`:

```
kkk[0.00754] - kkg[0.00754] // N
```

> ```
> {6.50604*10^-7}
> ```

---

Regarding `N`, it does not change the precision of machine precision numbers as it does for exact or arbitrary precision ones:

```
N[{1.23456789, Pi, 1.23456789`50}, 2]

Precision /@ %
```

> ```
> {1.23457, 3.1, 1.2}
>
> {MachinePrecision, 2., 2.}
> ```

Look at [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html) if you want to force (fake) a precision, and [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html) if you want to print a number in a specific format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer about precision! Then, well, after seeing your graph I rechecked mine and sadly found that I misread the coordinate on the graph……

Comment: @user1551513 hopefully `GridLines` will help with that in the future.  Also, you can right-click on the plot and choose **Get Coordinates** to help pin down a value.